# Is the notion of a set always a primitive notion?

Tags: set-theory

Is there an approach in set theory where we have a definition of a set, or do we always consider the notion of a set as being a primitive notion that cannot be defined in terms of previously defined other notions?

Comment: If you believe in the foundation axiom, you can take $\emptyset$ as your primitive notion. Then all other sets come from iterating powerset and union operations. Look into the well-founded universe for more information about this.

Comment: @William Well, that's in $\sf ZFC$. The OP isn't restricting himself to $\sf ZFC$, I believe.

Comment: @William: How do you define a "power set" without appealing to "set" in the first place?

Comment: To formally define what a set is (e.g. $x$ is a set iff...), you would also have to define what is *not* a set. It doesn't seem possible.

Comment: If, for example, you define $x$ to be a set iff $\exists a\in x$, then the so-called empty set could not exist. That would be very troublesome indeed.

Answer (score 7):

The $\lambda$-calculus (and similar systems defined using combinators) can be seen as an attempt to define a mathematical world in which everything is a function. See https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Illative_combinatory_logic for references.

More recent work on mathematical foundation systems of this kind generally involves some notion of type (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory) and it is a topic for debate whether type-theoretic foundations and set-theoretic foundations are really different. Proponents of type theory will generally say that they are.

Answer (score 2):

There are candidates for foundational theories, such as category theory and the theories that Rob mentions, in which the notion of "set" is not primitive, but I don't think these count as set theories even if they turn out to be mutually interpretable with set theories.

In set theory you can get close to what you want, I think, with [NBG set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_axioms#Axiomatizating_NBG) (the one-sorted formulation) in which "class" is the primitive notion and a set is defined as a class that is contained in some other class.

Comment: By a class do you mean an "object"?

Comment: @palio I'm not sure what your question means.  Could you clarify it?

Comment: Because many introductory books on set theory say that "a set is a well defined collection of distinct objects" and here "object" is always a primitive notion. And by the way what does "well defined" mean in this sentence? thank you !!

Comment: The sentence you quoted sounds like naive set theory rather than axiomatic set theory (note that the ZFC axioms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFC#The_axioms do not define "set".)  In the context of that sentence "well-defined" probably means defined by a logical formula (rather than by some fuzzy natural language definition.)