# Is there a set theory where functions are primitives?

Tags: functions, set-theory

It doesn't really sit right with me that functions between sets should themselves be defined as sets.  Is there some set theory that treats both sets and functions equally as basic notions instead of defining one in terms of the other?

Comment: What do you mean by a set theory treating sets and functions equally? Do you mean a theory in a two-sorted logic whose models can be considered as universes? Or let's say a theory in first-order logic with two mutually exclusive predicates? Can you say what benefits you expect from that?

Comment: Have you met category theory?

Comment: @martin.koeberl You're losing me with all the logic. o.O  I don't know if there are any benefits, I was just curious.

Comment: @Chappers Nope.  I looked up the ZFC axioms once.  That and the bits of set theory I've picked up here and there are all I know.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481232/is-the-notion-of-a-set-always-a-primitive-notion?rq=1 (the first answer for example)

Comment: http://rs.io/why-category-theory-matters/ , https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+theory , and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory should get you started, although a lot of category theory references expect you to know an undergraduate degree's–worth of algebra.

Comment: Not a set theory but you might be interested in type theories like  homotopy type theory.

Comment: All these are great.  Thanks you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lawvere's "Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets" (ETCS) is probably what you're looking for. Here are some links:

https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/01/an_elementary_theory_of_the_ca.html

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS

and the original article: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/11/tr11.pdf

It might be tricky if you haven't seen category theory yet, though.

Answer (score 2):

[Von Neumann set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory). From the Wikipedia page:

> In two articles published in 1925 and 1928, John von Neumann stated his axioms and showed they were adequate to develop set theory. **Von Neumann took functions and arguments as primitives.** His functions correspond to classes, and functions that can be used as arguments correspond to sets. In fact, he defined classes and sets using functions that can take only two values (that is, indicator functions whose domain is the class of all arguments).
>   
> von Neumann, John (1925), "[Eine Axiomatisierung der Mengenlehre](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN243919689_0154&DMDID=DMDLOG_0025)", Journal für die Reine und Angewandte Mathematik, 154: 219–240. English translation: van Heijenoort, Jean (1967), "An axiomatization of set theory", From Frege to Gödel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic, 1879-1931, Harvard University Press, pp. 393–413.
>   
> von Neumann, John (1928), "[Die Axiomatisierung der Mengenlehre](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN266833020_0027&DMDID=DMDLOG_0042)", Mathematische Zeitschrift, 27: 669–752, doi:10.1007/bf0117112